# UWP windows.preInstalledConfigTask running multiple times

Tags: uwp, background-task, out-of-process

I have created a uwp background task.This task suppose to run only once when app receive update. i have used below configuration in appmanifest file

```
 <Extension Category="windows.preInstalledConfigTask" EntryPoint="PreInstallTask.PreInstallTask" />
```

I found that on some system this task is running multiple timese. I am not sure why this is happening?

Comment: I have used this config. ' ' ' <Extension Category="windows.updateTask" EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.ApplicationUpdateTask" /> ' ' '

Comment: Hello, did you solve this problem by modifying the config? If yes, you can provide an answer. If you haven’t solved it, please elaborate on the specific characteristics of `some system` you refer to, what is different from the normally triggered system, and provide a sample for us to test.